# Complete Network Noob: please help me set-up Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, censorship, help

Hi all I'm trying to set up Tor on my school laptop to get around the schools censorship but I'm a wee bit stuck. I've put in the proxy that's required for access to the schools network, checked for open ports and got bridges but when I try to connect an error pops up `Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH]` and that all any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Log below. P.S. I'm using the standard Tor browser bundle.

```
20/05/2014 8:49:08 AM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server. 
20/05/2014 8:49:08 AM.301 [WARN] connection_connect(): Bug: Tried to open a socket with DisableNetwork set. 
20/05/2014 8:49:08 AM.302 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 1; recommendation warn) 
20/05/2014 8:49:12 AM.220 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 2; recommendation warn) 
20/05/2014 8:49:12 AM.221 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 3; recommendation warn)
```

Comment: i got that when my computer wasn't connected to the internet

Comment: yeah I'm pretty certain its connected.

Comment: haha, the fact that you're posting to stackexchange means you're connected, it was just a comment that may be useful information

Comment: Did you use 'normal' bridges or advanced technology liek FTE, Flashproxy or obfs3? The newer TBB lets you choose when setting up bridges.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your school's internet access is restricted to a white list of specific websites which only they are allowed to get surfed. If this is it, there is nothing you can do. Well, perhaps you can try using TAILS if there is something in the computer's software that disrupts the connection, but do not forget to turn off MAC Spoofing otherwise the Sysadmins will be on you in no time.

Answer (score 1):

They are likely blocking access to the directory services. I believe you have two options

1. do you school work
2. Use [bridges](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en)

Comment: 1.Ive done my work sir 2. I've got bridges

Comment: Are the bridges not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try pluggable transport. It will  work in a very restricted environment.